# Be authentic synonym of not having a mask?

Tags: expressions

In Spanish, we say that we all have a mask as we are not 100% authentic (at least all the time). Is that expression correct in English?

Comment: You just said it in English, and I understood it. That is at least some evidence that it is "correct" . . .

Comment: I'm sure Shakespeare said something along these lines at some point.

Comment: A more common idiom for _be authentic_  is _Show one's true colours_ or _Show your true colours_ http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/show+one%27s+true+colors although it's quite often used negatively as in someone you think is nice does something that makes you think they are not as nice as you originally thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the common English expression is:

> We all wear masks.

Or:

> Everyone wears a mask.

But the concept is the same, yes.